Decision Tree from Expert Experience
I am looking for decision trees which are hand-crafted by domain experts from their experience. As far as I know, medical practitioners have their empirical decision tree for diagnosis, I want to know whether other domains like Banking or Customer Relationship Management have a similar decision tree usage.
To be more specific, I am not looking for Decision Trees learnt by Machine Learning algorithms. Instead, it should be extracted from an expert's domain knowledge.
